# Odoo commit onchange to an other model

Tags: python, xml, odoo, decorator, odoo-8

I'm having a problem with the onchange decorator.

I have 2 model. Let's say `AAA` and `BBB`

`AAA` is used in the xml, and when the field `my_field` of this model is modify, it call an onchange method.

I have no difficulty for this onchange to modify any field of `AAA` but when I try to use it to modify `my_other_field` which is in `BBB` (and doesn't appear in xml) I can't figure out how to apply it.

in `AAA` I do have a many2one `BBB_id` to `BBB` and so I tried :

```
@api.onchange('my_field')
def onchange_my_field(self)
    if self.BBB_id:
        self.BBB_id.my_other_field = value
```

But I think that, since it is in an other model, the on_change don't do anything or at least doesn't commit the change.

I tried a lot of solutions I found on internet but none seams to have any effect.

Can someone tell me how to acces `my_other_field` which is in `BBB` from an onchange in `AAA` and/or how to commit the modification so it is registered?